# I want to make VLC my default player on Mac OS X 10.10.3

Tags: macos, vlc

I have seen people say to click get info then do something with the 'open with' but when I go to get info there is NO open with option, no options to change at all. I cannot drag the files into VLC like I could before the upgrade either. Please help me out! I am not real tech savvy, but I can do basics and follow instructions. Thanks.

Comment: Delete VLC and install it again. Seems to be an error in VLC application. Maybe consider to downgrade (VLC).

Answer (score 36):

Right click on any movie file you have.

Get Info

At the bottom of that window you will see the current app used to open it.

Change to VLC and use the "Change all"

[image] [image]

You need to repeat that for all movie files that have different extension.

Normally you would have .fvl, the .mov, and maybe some other formats.

Comment: There is NO current app listed, the bottom says Movie, and there is no option to change it. what next?

Comment: Do you have any movies at all ?

Comment: I am trying to play a video I took with my iPhone 6...that is what I am right clicking on...I guess that is a movie? I have other movie files that are no problem to play on VLC. These videos that are problems are in my iPhoto, would that make a difference?

Comment: ok, what does it show as what app is playing it (in the get info window)

Comment: here is what the get info window shows: img #, date and time taken,iphone6, no lens info, 7620x1280, 30.1MB, H.264, 30.01fps, 00:32, add description, Movie (movie is in a little blue box). no app that I see...

Comment: That is just not what I see in iPhoto when I right click on the files. I am right clicking on the thumbnail of the file...is that not the correct thing to right click on? I wish I knew how to screen shot it and post it here.

Comment: When I right click on other movies outside of iPhoto I see what you are talking about. But my iPhoto files do not show all of that. the iPhone files are .mov, but most of my movie files are mp4

Comment: sorry, my mistake, you have to right click in the Finder not in the iPhoto.

Comment: Ah yes, this seems to work. My issue was that the old way of setting a default app appeared to stop working (i.e. going to Open With > Other > selecting VLC > checking the Always Open With box). Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

I just tested a m4v file with VLC Version 2.2.1 and it works fine.  (Not sure what type of media files you are trying to open) So here is what I did:

Right click or ctrl+click on the media file
Open with > VLC
[image: VLC Open with from Finder]

The file opened just fine.
To open ALL files by that type:
Use the Get Info option. (in the picture) From there you can select [image: Change All]

Change all to use VLC with all files of this type.

I hope this is useful to you in solving your issue.

Comment: Try "View In Finder" to see if that helps.  As opposed to info in Photos app.

Comment: Thank you! I just had to understand that I cannot open the files while in iPhoto with VLC anymore, I have to go through finder.

Answer (score 1):

Choose a file in your Finder, left click on :

[image]

Choose VLC app and check the 'always open with' box

[image]

Comment: That only works for the current file, not all files with that file type.

Comment: VLC is not `appStore` trusted application, so the mac prevents to make it as a default application for video.